# In Django, when setting db_index to false for a field or removing 'db_index=True', does the index for the field get removed?

Tags: database, django, indexing

If not, is the easiest way to remove it to manually remove the index tables through Django's dbshell?

This is for the purpose of load testing; I want to test the database with indexing turned on for on certain fields and test it without indexing for the same fields.

Answer (score 1):

Not automatically, you'll need to make a database migration to add or remove an index, you can use [`south`](http://south.aeracode.org/) for this purpose.